# When I hover over a div I want the background of it to change white from black and the text of the link to turn black from white

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

The background of my div is black and the text of the link is white.

```
#menu {
 background-color:black;
 width:20%;
 float:left;
}
```

And the actual div.

```
<div id="menu"><a href="http://menu.com">Menu</a>
```

How can I make it so that when I hover over it the link text turns black and the background of the div turns black?

Comment: check this link : 
http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/QWD36/3/

One works and One fails,
because of priority of selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use :hover pseudo class

#menu:hover a {
color: #000;
}

#menu:hover  {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: thanks I tried #menu:link #menu:hover {...} but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: did you used #menu:hover a {} instead of anchor tag class name ??

did you defined background color of #menu  like this :
#menu { background: #000 } ??

Answer (score 0):

Is this your desired output?

```
<div id="menu"><a href="http://menu.com">Menu</a></div>

#menu {
 background-color:black;
 width:20%;
 float:left;
}
a{
    color: white;
}
#menu:hover
{
    background-color: white;
}
#menu:hover a
{
    color: black;
}
```